# Ploting constant contours in the same color in matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

```
[x,y] = meshgrid(-10:1:10,-10:1:10); 
idx = (x~=0)&(y~=0);     
contour(x(idx)/(x(idx).^2+y(idx).^2).^(3/2),y(idx)/(x(idx).^‌2+y(idx).^2).^(3/2))‌​;
```

the output is white page!

Comment: Try a [mcve].  Just define your x,y with your constrain, you choose what to plot, you have chosen to plot x=0,y=0

Comment: I don't know how to choose not to plot x=0 and y=0 @AnderBiguri

Comment: Read my first comment again. Do what it says

Comment: I did. Could you please help me now? @AnderBiguri

Comment: No because you did not read the link I gave you. Now is Minimal. You lack Complete, and Verifiable. I can not run that code becuase x and y are undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"delete" the points you do not want:

```
[x,y] = meshgrid(-10:0.1:10,-10:0.1:10);
Idontwantthis = (x.^2+y.^2)<1;
data= x./(x.^2+y.^2).^(3/2)+y./(x.^2+y.^2).^(3/2);
data(Idontwantthis)=NaN;
contourf(data,20);
```

Note that I replaced `/` by `./`

I also added more points, as your meshgrid is tiny.

This is what the result looks like if you use `contourf` instead of `contour` (same thing, nicer looking):[image]

Comment: Error: The input character is not valid in MATLAB statements or expressions. this error comes out wgen I run your code

Comment: it works but shows lots of numbers in matlab command window. when I put ; after the second line of the code, still there are lots of numbers in output. How can I change the code to not show them?

Comment: @SoniaSohi the problem is in the function you defined, it has a coma in the middle. Fix your function, then I'll fix mine

Comment: What does colors mean in the output? When I run below code, right circles become red and left ones become green: clear all;
close all;
%[x,y] = meshgrid(-10:0.1:10,-10:0.1:10);
%Idontwantthis = (x.^2+y.^2)<1;
%data= x./(x.^2+y.^2).^(3/2),y./(x.^2+y.^2).^(3/2);
%data(Idontwantthis)=NaN;
%contourf(data,20);

[x,y] = meshgrid(-10:0.1:10,-10:0.1:10);
Idontwantthis = (x.^2+y.^2)<1;
data= x./(x.^2+y.^2).^(3/2),y./(x.^2+y.^2).^(3/2);
data(Idontwantthis)=NaN;
contourf(data,20);

Comment: Why is output in the interval 20:200?

Comment: 1) get rid of that coma 2) you mean the result of the equation? You defined the eqution, you know why its values are what they are

Comment: @SoniaSohi if you want to change the x-y axes, then `contourf(x,y,...)`

Comment: Could you please answer my friend's question. I'm sure you are one who could answer it. We have the same problem using parfor:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44352171/parfor-doesnt-consider-information-about-vectors-which-are-used-in-it