# Combining two images in matlab (contourf changes the range of the plot)

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I wrote below code to show a simple vector field and it's magnitude. I want to combine two images but the first one is plotted in an interval which I didn't want and when I type hold on, the second image is shown in a very small region of the first image! But I want them to be shown in the same regions. Could anyone help?

```
clear all;
close all;
[x,y] = meshgrid(-3:0.1:3,-3:0.1:3);
Idontwantthis = (x.^2+y.^2)<1;
data= sqrt((x./(x.^2+y.^2).^(3/2)).^2+(y./(x.^2+y.^2).^(3/2)).^2);
data(Idontwantthis)=NaN;
contourf(data,20);
u = (10000*x./(x.^2+y.^2).^(3/2));
v = (10000*y./(x.^2+y.^2).^(3/2));

figure
quiver(x,y,u,v)
```

The code is from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44305405/ploting-constant-contours-in-the-same-color-in-matlab)

Comment: This code is familiar.......

Comment: Yes. I tried to generalize your answer to a question. Should a ask for permission?! @AnderBiguri If yes, I can ask you or delete the question

Comment: Nah, just add a link from wherever you get the code, not just this time

Comment: Done. Would you remove your negative score?@AnderBiguri

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not mentioning the locations while using *contourf*, so it is getting plotted w.r.t to indices. You have to mention the locations, so that you can use hold on.

```
[x,y] = meshgrid(-3:0.1:3,-3:0.1:3);
Idontwantthis = (x.^2+y.^2)<1;
data= sqrt((x./(x.^2+y.^2).^(3/2)).^2+(y./(x.^2+y.^2).^(3/2)).^2);
data(Idontwantthis)=NaN;
contourf(x,y,data,20);
u = (10000*x./(x.^2+y.^2).^(3/2));
v = (10000*y./(x.^2+y.^2).^(3/2));

u(Idontwantthis)=NaN;
v(Idontwantthis)=NaN;
% figure
hold on
quiver(x,y,u,v)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But still it seems that they do not match because there is a white region which there are arrows on it.

Comment: According to the data which you gave...the image is correct...what you expecting?

Comment: I expect in the regions where vectors exist, there be colour

Comment: what color? You mean the contours ?

Comment: Yes I don't expect this region to be white

Comment: Are you aware what you doing? That particular part is changed to NaN..using the indices..how you expect it to be colored? Okay, fine tell me which color you want instead of white?

Comment: Yes, I change that part to NAN but I expect NAN part to be NAN for vectors also. I expect no vector in NAN region

Comment: In that case...you have to change U and V to NaN...check the edited code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145680/discussion-between-siva-srinivas-kolukula-and-oliver-range).

Comment: How can I make the arrows bigger?

Comment: Read the documentation yaar...quiver(x,y,u,v,N), N is your size...mention a number there.