# parfor doesn't consider information about vectors which are used in it

Tags: matlab, optimization, parfor

This is a part of my code in Matlab. I tried to make it parallel but there is an error:

```
 The variable gax in a parfor cannot be classified.
```

I know why the error occurs. because I should tell Matlab that v is an incresing vector which doesn't contain repeated elements. Could anyone help me to use this information to parallelize the code?

```
v=[1,3,6,8];
ggx=5.*ones(15,14);
gax=ones(15,14);
for m=v
if m > 1 
    parfor j=1:m-1
        gax(j,m-1) = ggx(j,m-1); 
    end
end
if m<nn 
    parfor jo=m+1:15 
        gax(jo,m) = ggx(jo,m); 
    end
end
end
```

Comment: Do you know how can I fix this problem? @EBH

Comment: What is `v1`? Also, one of the problems is with using the loop index for both row and column when assigning to `gax`. [_"Form of Indexing — Within the list of indices for the variable, exactly one index involves the loop variable."_](http://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/sliced-variable.html)

Comment: And [_"The array maintains a constant shape"_](http://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/sliced-variable.html), so `gax(1:m-1,m-1)` is not allowed because `1:m-1` may have a different size on every iteration.

Comment: I added the v1. But there is no matter if (for example) one worker is doing with m=3 and another worker with m=5 in the same time. They don't have conflict and I think there should be a way to write above code somehow which it could work by parfor @EBH

Comment: I didn't say you can't write it, just pointed the real problems, so you'll know where to look. If I'll have time later I'll try to fix this. Please read the [link above](http://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/sliced-variable.html) carefully, as they explain what is permitted when calling a sliced variable. Remember that even if something looks _possible_ to you, as long as you use Matlab, Then Mathworks define the rule.

Comment: @EBH I read the link and wrote below code. But it still doesn't work :( : parfor i = 1:length(v1)
     m = v(i);
     if m > 1
         for j=1:m-1
         gax(j,m-1) = ggx(j,m-1);
         end 
     end
     if m<nn
         for jo=m+1:15
         gax(jo,m) = ggx(jo,m);
         end
     end
 end

Comment: In [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44352171/parfor-doesnt-consider-information-about-vectors-which-are-used-in-it#comment75707982_44352171) you call to `gax(j,m-1)` and then to `gax(jo,m)` within the same `parfor` and that is also not permitted. The sliced variable should be indexed the same through all the loop. Also, replace `parfor i = 1:length(v1) m = v(i);` with `parfor m = v`.

Comment: What about this one? v=[1,3,6,8];
 ggx=5.*ones(15,14);
 gax=ones(15,14);
for m=v
    if m > 1 
        parfor j=1:m-1
            gax(j,m-1) = ggx(j,m-1); 
        end
    end
    if m<nn 
        parfor jo=m+1:15 
            gax(jo,m) = ggx(jo,m); 
        end
    end
end

Comment: It still doesn't work @EBH

Comment: I know. It's just another step in the right direction. And please fix your question, `v1` is not defined in your code.

Comment: :(( It is really complicated to solve @EBH

Comment: There is no v1 @EBH. Done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Optimizing a code should be closely related to its purpose, especially when you use `parfor`. The code you wrote in the question can be written in a much more efficient way, and definitely, do not need to be parallelized.

However, I understand that you tried to simplify the problem, just to get the idea of how to slice your variables, so here is a fixed version the *can* run with `parfor`. But this is surely not the way to write this code:

```
v = [1,3,6,8];
ggx = 5.*ones(15,14);
gax = ones(15,14);
nn = 5;
for m = v
    if m > 1
        temp_end = m-1;
        temp = ggx(:,temp_end);
        parfor ja = 1:temp_end
            gax(ja,temp_end) = temp(ja);
        end
    end
    if m < nn
        temp = ggx(:,m);
        parfor jo = m+1:15
            gax(jo,m) = temp(jo);
        end
    end
end
```

A vectorized implementation will look like this:

```
v = [1,3,6,8];
ggx = 5.*ones(15,14);
gax = ones(15,14);
nn = 5;

m1 = v>1; % first condition with logical indexing
temp = v(m1)-1; % get the values from v
r = ones(1,sum(temp)); % generate a vector of indicies
r(cumsum(temp)) = -temp+1; % place the reseting locations
r = cumsum(r); % calculate the indecies
r(cumsum(temp)) = temp; % place the ending points
c = repelem(temp,temp); % create an indecies vector for the columns
inds1 = sub2ind(size(gax),r,c); % convert the indecies to linear

mnn = v<nn; % second condition with logical indexing
temp = v(mnn)+1; % get the values from v
r_max = size(gax,1); % get the height of gax
r_count = r_max-temp+1; % calculate no. of rows per value in v
r = ones(1,sum(r_count)); % generate a vector of indicies
r([1 r_count(1:end-1)+1]) = temp; % set the t indicies
r(cumsum(r_count)+1) = -(r_count-temp)+1; % place the reseting locations
r = cumsum(r(1:end-1)); % calculate the indecies
c = repelem(temp-1,r_count); % create an indecies vector for the columns
inds2 = sub2ind(size(gax),r,c); % convert the indecies to linear

gax([inds1 inds2]) = ggx([inds1 inds2]); % assgin the relevant values
```

This is indeed quite complicated, and not always necessary. A good thing to remember, though, is that nested `for` loop are much slower than a single loop, so in some cases (depend on the size of the output), this will may be the fastest solution:

```
for m = v
    if m > 1
        gax(1:m-1,m-1) = ggx(1:m-1,m-1);
    end
    if m<nn
        gax(m+1:15,m) = ggx(m+1:15,m);
    end
end
```

Comment: What is the best way (the less time consuming)to write this code?

Comment: If these are the size and shape of your data - vectorize it, i.e. don't use loops at all.

Comment: The data is bigger than this size. v is a 1000 by 1 vector. gax and ggx are 1000 by 1 and this part of the code is located in another for loop with 1 million repeats! What is better to do in this case?

Comment: Here `gax` and `ggx` are matrices, and you say that in your code they are vectors, so what exactly you do with them. What part of the code do you want to parallelize?

Comment: gax and ggx are 1000 by 999 matrices n my code. I wanted to make code faster. So I decided to parallelize this loop. But it seems that it make if worst

Comment: @OliverRange, The communication with the workers in `parfor` has it's 'price', so unless you give them a big enough task to do on each iteration, it does not worth parallelizing. Also, if you are not dealing with a lot of data (how much is a lot? that depends on your machine), it worth vectorizing your code.

Comment: Could the above code be vectorized more than what I have wrote?

Comment: @OliverRange - see my edit for a vectorized solution.

Comment: Thank you very much. Is it really more sufficient than the code I wrote(without parfor)? It looks very complicated!

Comment: I think this one is less time conuming: for m=v
if m > 1 
    for j=1:m-1
        gax(j,m-1) = ggx(j,m-1); 
    end
end
if m<nn 
    for jo=m+1:15 
        gax(jo,m) = ggx(jo,m); 
    end
end
end

Comment: @OliverRange, see my edit for a better use of `for`.

Comment: It is odd but complicated approach is less consuming!

Comment: @OliverRange, this is because more code does no imply more time to run, it really depends on the details.